# NHibernate / Castle.ActiveRecord ; delete fails because row was updated in same transaction

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

this is realy crazy now. I am trying to delete some objects that have hirachical relations with each other but somehow then NHibernate (or ActiverRecord) first updates the relations (foreigen keys) and then tries a delete in the same transaction, but the delete fails becaus of the concurrency check (optimistic locking all).

Pseudocode of my classes:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Box : ActiveRecordBase
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public virtual int BoxId{get;set;}
  [BelongsTo]
  public virtual Box TopLevelBox{get;set;}
  [BelongsTo]
  public virtual Box Parent {get;set;}
  [HasMany]
  public virtual IList<Box> Children {get;set;}
  [HasMany]
  public virtual IList<Content> Conten{get;set;}
}

[ActiveRecord]
public class Content : ActiveRecordBase
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public virtual int ContentId{get;set;}
  [BelongsTo]
  public virtual Box Box{get;set;}
}
```

I have 3 Boxes and 3 Contents. I am trying to describe the strucutre:

```
Box1.Parent = null;
Box1.TopLevelBox = Box1;
Box1.Children = {Box2,Box3};
Box1.Content = {Conten1};
Box2.Parent = Box1;
Box2.TopLevelBox = Box1;
Box2.Children = {};
Box2.Content = {Content2};
Box3.Parent = Box1;
Box3.TopLevelBox = Box1;
Box3.Children = {};
Box3.Content = {Content3};
Content3.Box = Box3;
Content2.Box = Box2;
Content1.Box = Box1;
```

When I let NHibernate output then it does following silly things:

```
UPDATE box1 SET toplevelbox = NULL WHERE [optimistic locking all checks];
UPDATE box2 SET parent = NULL, toplevelbox = NULL WHERE [optimistic locking all checks];
UPDATE box3 SET parent = NULL, toplevelbox = NULL WHERE [optimistic locking all checks];
UPDATE content1 SET box = NULL WHERE [optimistic locking all checks];
UPDATE content2 SET box = NULL WHERE [optimistic locking all checks];
UPDATE content3 SET box = NULL WHERE [optimistic locking all checks];
DELETE box1 WHERE [optimistic locking all checks but with] AND topleveobox = box1;
// Of cause this last check fails and my transaction get's a rollback
```

What is worong here? How to stop NHibernat (or ActiveRecord) from doing that silly updates?

I am realy despaired and need help.

Greetings

Juy Juka

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is inverse. Then the many-to-one part is responsible for the association. Note: You have to take care that the parent reference of the box is always maintained

```
[HasMany(Inverse = true)]
public virtual IList<Box> Children {get;set;}
[HasMany(Inverse = true)]
public virtual IList<Content> Content {get;set;}
```